# MySQL stored procedure, variable with variable name

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures

I'd like to reference a variable using another variable. Basically I have 7 address fields (address1, address2, etc.) and it would save a lot of coding to make a loop from 1 to 7. Here's a basic situation where I need this:

```
Naddress1 = replace(Naddress1,'.','');
Naddress2 = replace(Naddress2,'.','');
Naddress3 = replace(Naddress3,'.','');
Naddress4 = replace(Naddress4,'.','');
Naddress5 = replace(Naddress5,'.','');
Naddress6 = replace(Naddress6,'.','');
Naddress7 = replace(Naddress7,'.','');
Naddress1 = replace(Naddress1,',',' ');
Naddress2 = replace(Naddress2,',',' ');
Naddress3 = replace(Naddress3,',',' ');
Naddress4 = replace(Naddress4,',',' ');
Naddress5 = replace(Naddress5,',',' ');
Naddress6 = replace(Naddress6,',',' ');
Naddress7 = replace(Naddress7,',',' ');
Naddress1 = replace(Naddress1,'/'',' ');
Naddress2 = replace(Naddress2,'/'',' ');
Naddress3 = replace(Naddress3,'/'',' ');
Naddress4 = replace(Naddress4,'/'',' ');
Naddress5 = replace(Naddress5,'/'',' ');
Naddress6 = replace(Naddress6,'/'',' ');
Naddress7 = replace(Naddress7,'/'',' ');
```

What I'd like:

```
DECLARE address_iterator INT;
SET address_iterator = 1;
WHILE address_iterator <= 7 DO
Naddress & address_iterator = replace(Naddress & address_iterator, '.','');
Naddress & address_iterator = replace(Naddress & address_iterator, ',',' ');
Naddress & address_iterator = replace(Naddress & address_iterator, '/'',' ');
END WHILE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL you could do something like this -

```
UPDATE
  table
SET
  address1 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(address1, '.', ''), ',',' '), '/',' '),
  address2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(address2, '.', ''), ',',' '), '/',' '),
  address3 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(address3, '.', ''), ',',' '), '/',' ');
```

Otherwise you should automate this task in application.

Comment: Forgot to mention this is in a stored procedure, but this answer helps a lot! thanks